# SpringBoot overriding AnnotationConfigApplicationContext throws no such bean defined

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-restcontroller

I have got the problem. I want to override AnnotationConfigApplicationContext. But I got NoSuchBeanDefinition.

I have got some class, which has constructor and any methods

```
import com.package.pack1;

public class Train {

 public Train (){}

 ...//other methods
}
```

Also I use @SpringBootApplication to start it on tomcat 7

```
import com.package.pack2;


@SpringBootApplication
public class SpringBootTomcatApplication extends SpringBootServletInitializer {

        private AnnotationConfigApplicationContext context;

        public static void main(String[] args) {
            SpringApplication.run(SpringBootTomcatApplication.class, args);
        }

        @Override
        protected SpringApplicationBuilder configure(SpringApplicationBuilder application) {
                    context = new AnnotationConfigApplicationContext();
                    Train train = new Train();
                    context.getBeanFactory().registerSingleton("Train",train); 
                    context.scan("com.package.pack1");
                    context.refresh();
                    return application.sources(SpringBootTomcatApplication.class);
        }



}
```

And controller where I need to use Train.class from autowired

```
package com.package.pack2;

import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;

@RestController
public class HelloController {

@Autowired
private Train train;


}
```

But when I start it on server. I have got the message: on HelloController NoSuchBeanDefinition to parameter Train. Please help me.

**Stacktrace:**

> Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'HelloController ': Injection of autowired dependencies failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: private Train train; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.**NoSuchBeanDefinitionException**: No qualifying bean of type [сom.package.pack1.Train] found for dependency: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate for this dependency. Dependency annotations: {@org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)}
>       at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessPropertyValues(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:292)
>       at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1180)
>       at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:537)
>       at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:475)
>       at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:300)
>       at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:228)
>       at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:296)
>       at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:195)
>       at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:660)
>       at org.springframework.context.support.AnnotationConfigApplicationContext .finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AnnotationConfigApplicationContext .java:760)
>       at org.springframework.context.support.AnnotationConfigApplicationContext .refresh(AnnotationConfigApplicationContext .java:482)
>       at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.refresh(EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.java:122)
>       at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:552)

Comment: can you post the complete error message with stack trace

Comment: add stack trace

Comment: @Deadpool yes, it doesn`t work